# Using WPF custom compositefont from dll resource

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I have a custom composite font as a resource in a library dll that I'd like to load but I'm unable to get the exact syntax.  I tried:

```
FontFamily font = new FontFamily(
  new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyLibraryDll"), 
  "./fonts/#My Font from composite font");
```

Which didn't work so I tried enumerating the fonts with:

```
ICollection<FontFamily> fonts = Fonts.GetFontFamilies(
   new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyLibraryDll"), 
   "./fonts/#My Font from composite font");
```

And

```
ICollection<FontFamily> fonts = Fonts.GetFontFamilies(
  new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyLibraryDll"),
  "./fonts/mycompositefont.compositefont#My Font from composite font");
```

And both return a count of 0.  There is no documentation on these that I can find -- has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Packaging Fonts with Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx), the correct syntax is:

```
new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,"),
    "MyLibraryDll;Component/Fonts/#My Font from composite font");
```